# What's wrong with this simple PCB design? (midi synth)

Tags: arduino, pcb, noise, midi, synthesizer

I am designing a simple synth with Arduino (just the Atmega IC) and it works fine. The only thing is this annoying *clicks* I barely hear constantly if I raise the volume somewhat.

I had this problem in the past that's why I was trying to fix it by designing the PCB, separating 3 ground sectors in digital and analogue parts on one side of the PCB. In theory that should stop the digital part contaminating the analogue part.
It seems it didn't quite worked because I can still hear the *clicks*.

**There are two things making clicks at the same time**, according to my tests:

**1- the Atmega crystal:** If I remove the Atmega IC, that click stop.
**UPDATE: **That click was caused by the Atmega program. But I still have this other midi click sounds:

**2- the Midi messages:** When Midi is not connected, there is no click. After each midi message is sent (a note or clock i.e) I hear a click. For example the clock makes a constant stream of clicks and are sped up if I increase the tempo on the master device sending the BPM. **If I take the Atmega IC and send midi messages, I can hear the clicks, so it's independent of it. That's why I'm thinking it's a PCB design issue**

**To strip down the problem I removed the LM358 part where the "scissors" are in the schematic picture and I just get the output from where it says PWM, that's just the output from the atmega IC.**

So, my question is: **Do you see any PCB design flaws? What could be causing the *click* noises?**

Thanks!!

PD: I can upload the Eagle file if requested.
[image: PCB]][]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if you are totally on-point with what you're doing here... you do realize that removing the crystal probably makes the program stop running, right? Have you tried changing the software to see what effect that has?

Comment: Your clicks may well be caused by servicing the Arduino core's timer, this is pretty notorious for interfering with delay-sensitive ongoing operations.  The audible result may not be at the timer rate, but rather at a harmonic difference between that and the rate of the time-sensitive operation.

Comment: Indeed, that is most probably a software problem. Like an interrupt service request that gets in the way. It wouldn't happen without crystal because then, the atmega switches to the internal oscillator and the timings are not the same anymore, and it wouldn't happen when midi is not used because then, there is no such interrupt to service. I doubt this could be a PCB layout problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What I'm doing is removing the Atmega IC, not the crystal. I know it stops the program, what I meant to prove is that one of the clicks come from the Atmega (or it's crystal).
Ok, just now I loaded an empty program and that click stoped. You were all right about it, thanks to all!
**But there is a louder click present each time Midi messages are received, that is my main concern!**
I really don't know what else to try. What about ferrites? Don't know how to use it and I don't think I can get them here in my city :/

Comment: Can you record the output with an oscilloscope?

Comment: "But there is a louder click present each time Midi messages are received" this is most likely a software problem and needs to be fixed in software.  It will not be trivial - the first requirement will be to understand every bit of software running on the device, which means either studying or removing the utilized Arduino core code.

Comment: The 'click' or discontinuity is probably being caused by the extra processing overhead of the MIDI message reception. You may be able to go in and optimize this and reduce the problem... but if your microcontroller is busy thinking about its input rather than generating sound output, you are going to get a click. Another approach would be to figure out how to prioritize generating the sound over *all* other tasks, but that could introduce other problems as well.

Comment: @CL: I recorded the audio, if you zoom in on a sound editor you can see the wave shape. They are just thin spikes. This is the clock midi message beeing received. At first I speed it from 100BPM to 300BPM and then I lower it again, that's why you can hear a tone. The gain of the audio file has been raised so you can hear the clicks easily.

I discovered that it seems that this clicks are "in the air" and picked up by the LM358 opamp even if I take the Atmega is out, and even if I connect the opamp input to GND I can still hear it being amplified.

Comment: forgot to add the file, here it is!
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103115555/midi%20clock.wav

Answer (score 4):

The [6N137 datasheet](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-0940EN) says:

> A 0.1 μF bypass capacitor must be connected between pins 5 and 8.

This is required not only to prevent the 6N137 itself from oscillating, but also protects the rest of the circuit from dips in the power supply.

You have an inductor in front of the ATmega's digital power supply, but it might be a better idea to move/copy it to protect the analog part of your circuit from *any* of the digital parts.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I tried from a 0.1uF to a 3300uF and the sound is the same.
As you advised also I have cut the VCC trace and connected it thru an inductor but didn't do anything.